# Update data two element in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, nodes

```
 {
 "Templates": [
      {
        "ProductId": "63a2b0f87a810608e6ca6d95",
        "RevisionNum": [
            "221222"
        ],
        "EffectiveDate": "2022-12-22T02:45:22.587Z",
        "HardwareVer": "A",
        "SoftwareVer": "1.0",
        "WorkTasks": [],
        "_id": "63a3c4d950b22e564d2b8dee"
     }
],
"_id": "63a3c4d950b22e564d2b8ded",
"__v": 0
}
```

Update data element by productId one are update value in array ["221222"] to ["111111"] in RevisionNum array other are for HardwareVer in MongoDB and Nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrayFilters as follow:

```
db.collection.update({},
{
 $set: {
 "Templates.$[y].RevisionNum.$[x]": "1111",
 "Templates.$[y].HardwareVer": "B"
 }
},
{
 arrayFilters: [
 {
   x: "221222"
 },
 {
  "y.ProductId": "63a2b0f87a810608e6ca6d95"
 }
]
})
```

Explained:

Create two arrayFilters x & y to identify the element that you need to update.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GUQFAxM46j7)